# Android, APK returning to previous version after reboot

Tags: android, apk

I'm writing a software for a customer; that software will be pre-installed onto a custom ROM.

One of the features of that software is update it-self to a newer version when available.

Everything works well, but the problem is this; when the device is rebooted or restarted, the updated version disappears! The old version returns.

There is something different to be write to create pre-installed software that can be updated?

Thank you in advance for any guidance/suggestions.

Comment: I would venture a guess to say that either the file permissions are not right, you are not creating the UID/folders correctly, or something that the software installer does is not done as expected.

Comment: Sorry about my low knowledge, but what is UID/folders?!

Comment: Did you find any solution. I am facing same problem.

Comment: Yes, I was not changing the VERSIONCODE in manifest. Change this and it will work.

Answer (score 9):

I finally fixed the problem. So stupid by the way :) Because I was not updating the APK using Google Play, I was not changing the VERSIONCODE in Manifest! Just that. Everything else was ok. So, if someone else has the same problem, this is my tip: always change the versionCode and versionName.

Thank you for your help!

Best regards,
Joubert

Comment: Thank you, this is the right thing to do. And it's still working on android 5+!

Comment: On Nougat OS, it is not working for pre-installed APK into a custom ROM  )-:

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing there's a conflict with the APK in question when you do an update. Since you stated that the *software will be pre-installed onto a custom ROM*, that implies the software is signed with the ROM's signing key used.

So, it sounds like the key that you used to sign the APK is different to the ROM's signed key thereby reverting back to the old version?

Comment: Well, I'm signing with the same certificate. Can the manufacturer resign the apk?

Comment: Do you happen to have the system certificate signing keys (the ones that was used on the ROM)? If so, you could use that to sign the apk each time prior to deployment.

Comment: I don't have them. But in the same ROM there are two more custom APK from Google Play: Airdroid and ZdBox. Both can be updated without problems. I think I need to have another permissions or something like that.

Comment: Maybe if you use the `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in your manifest?

Comment: It Didn't work. I asked the manufacturer to generate a new ROM with a new version with that information. Let's see if it will work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any update? On Nougat OS, it is not working for pre-installed APK into a custom ROM )-:

Comment: @Joubert Vasconcelos , did your manufacturer provide any solution for that?

Comment: I just change the VersionCode any time I have a new version and it's ok now.